# IndexedFaceSet creates extra faces in x3d file

Tags: x3d, x3dom

I  have created an x3d file using x3dom. Following is the structure of the file. Copy the following code into text editor and save it as .x3d file. For imgage texture you can consider any jpg file and place it at the same location as x3d.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE X3D PUBLIC "ISO//Web3D//DTD X3D 3.0//EN"      
"http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.0.dtd">
<X3D profile='Interchange' version='3.0'    
xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.0.xsd'>
<Scene>
   <NavigationInfo type='"EXAMINE" "WALK" "FLY" "ANY"'/>
   <DirectionalLight intensity="0.8" direction="0 1 0"/>
   <DirectionalLight intensity="0.9" direction="0 -1 0"/>
   <DirectionalLight intensity="0.6" direction="1 0 -1"/>
   <DirectionalLight intensity="0.6" direction="-1 0 -1"/>
   <DirectionalLight intensity="0.6" direction="-1 0 1"/>
   <DirectionalLight intensity="0.6" direction="1 0 1"/>
   <Shape>
      <Appearance>
         <Material ambientIntensity="0.2" diffuseColor="0.004 0.004 0.004" emissiveColor="0 0 0" shininess="0.2" specularColor="0 0 0" transparency="0"/>
         <ImageTexture url="Penguins.jpg"/>
      </Appearance>
   <IndexedFaceSet convex="true" coordIndex="0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 -1 " ccw="true">
       <Coordinate point="132.2349 0 329.9732 123.0347 0 336.9273 109.9391 0 350.0229 102.985 0 359.223 82.26761 0 386.6317 69.30841 0 436.438 74.03987 0 470.4683 78.77134 0 504.4987 104.8261 0 548.8805 132.2349 0 569.598 191.8598 0 569.598 191.8598 0 689.9727 911.8589 0 689.9727 1032.234 0 569.598 1032.234 0 270.3483 852.2339 0 270.3483 852.2339 0 210.7232 371.8596 0 210.7232 371.8596 0 329.9732"/>
   </IndexedFaceSet>
  </Shape>
  <Viewpoint description="Center of Space" fieldOfView="0.785" position="553.1368 60 450.348"/>
 </Scene>
</X3D>
```

Looking it from the top view the 3D object looks like this,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRx6I.png)

And from the bottom view it looks like this,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo8CA.png)

I have checked all the points and they are in proper sequence but not sure why these two extra faces are created. Anything I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You draw a non-convex shape, therefor you need to set convex to false, in addition if you want to see your shape from "behind" you need to set solid to false.

This works:

```
<IndexedFaceSet convex="false" solid="false" coordIndex="0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 -1">
```

(you dont need ccw, its true by default)